# Como usar SQLite em aplicações CLI escritas em dart?

Tags: sqlite, dart, cli

Estou testando o [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) para discutir sua viabilidade em substituir parte da *code base* em Java. Não achei algo semelhante à especificação JDBC em Dart, então estou supondo que a linguagem não fornece um acesso padronizado a bancos de dados.

Procurando por SQL no https://pub.dev, não encontrei resultados resultados para SQLite em aplicações CLI, apenas carregados das tag `WEB` e `FLUTTER` (esperava a tag `OTHER`).

> Para SQL na tag `OTHER`, por enquanto só achei [`dart_mssql`](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mssql)
>
> Para SQLite, achei o [`dart:web_sql`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-web_sql/dart-web_sql-library.html) para `WEB` e [`sqflite`](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) para `FLUTTER`

Então, como usar SQLite para um programinha CLI em dart?

Comment: Achei algo como exemplo no próprio SDK do Dart, que permitiria fazer a linkagem de funções C no Dart: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/samples/ffi/sqlite/docs/sqlite-tutorial.md ; e esse exemplo específico é de como habilitar o SQLite em Dart cli/server